# Error generating images

Tags: 8, media

I was experiencing weird GD library issues with Drupal 8, when the site tries to generate thumbnails from image style. I am using [Docker PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

The error is simply saying *Error generating image*. I checked the logs, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is the fix for the issue.

The code taken from duplicated issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359917/docker-gd-module-for-php-7

Please take this with heaps of grain and salt, and modify the script accordingly.

```
# Install GD
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

What is actually happens is your GD library is installed **BUT without JPEG library configured**. Your Drupal will be chill saying GD installed but there is hidden requirement that JPEG need to be exist too.

The line 179 in GDToolkit.php:

```
$function = 'imagecreatefrom' . image_type_to_extension($this->getType(), FALSE);
```

Causes the function imagecreateformjpeg fails to be executed.

Hope it helps someone that confused, cant generate thumbnail with limited knowledge of the errors.

:)